# rails console starting in production error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The following errors appears when I try to run rails console in production. (In development mode it works as expected)

```
bin$ RAILS_ENV=production ./rails c
/home/ubuntu/app/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `load_missing_constant': Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant AdminUser (RuntimeError)
```

My AdminUser contains the following:

```
 class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460756/circular-dependency-detected-while-autoloading-constant-when-loading-constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pluralizing all the controllers under /admin fixed this issue

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2334#issuecomment-42626409

Answer (score 0):

It'll be more helpful if you can post code for AdminUser

check your code (AdminUser) for circular references like

1: callback triggering the same callback (update self after update)
2: method calling the same method

Comment: My AdminUser doesn't have much it extends ApplicationRecord and contains the devise settings. I'm editing the question with the contents of the file